# Splitting data from col into multiple cols

Tags: sql, sum, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table which looks like
[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB6vP.png)

So the ask is to concatenate row 1 and 2, the total of each month against each row. Output will look something like this:
[desired o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOp4T.png)
(the rows marked in orange are the same, hence should not be duplicated).

How would I achieve this through SQL?

tried the below queey but doesnt seem to work

```
select concat(s.JD_WS_CD, '_',s.JD_WS_SUB_CD, '_', s.JD_SHP_TO),
s.amt1 as Mar,
a.amt1 as Apr,
b.amt1 as Aug 
from  s 
cross join 
 a
cross join 
 b
where 
s.ym = '202304'
and
a.ym= '202305'
and
b.ym= '202308'
```

but i cant seem to get rid of the duplicates. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the requirement has changed. Here's how to do the updated requirements:

```sql
select
    concat(s.JD_WS_CD, '_', s.JD_WS_SUB_CD, '_', s.JD_SHP_TO),
    s.JD_WS_SUB_CD,
    s.JD_SHP_TO,
    SUM(CASE YM WHEN 201203 THEN AMT1 ELSE 0 END) AS MAR,
    SUM(CASE YM WHEN 201204 THEN AMT1 ELSE 0 END) AS APR,
    SUM(CASE YM WHEN 201208 THEN AMT1 ELSE 0 END) AS AUG
FROM
    s
GROUP BY
    s.JD_WS_CD,
    s.JD_WS_SUB_CD,
    s.JD_SHP_TO
```

We wanted to have different columns for each month. Then we've created conditions using CASE WHEN for the sum of the amount, filtered using the respective month. Then we've used group by instead of windowing function to remove duplications.

Here's a fiddle: [LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f01705/3/0)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use MAX();

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (
    JD_WS_CD INT,
    JD_WS_SUB_CD INT,
    JD_SHP_TO INT,
    YM NCHAR(6),
    ANT1 INT
);

-- Inserting the data from the image
INSERT INTO @TEMP (JD_WS_CD, JD_WS_SUB_CD, JD_SHP_TO, YM, ANT1)
VALUES
    (253, 1, 29306412, N'201203', 3634),
    (253, 1, 34300301, N'201203', 1817),
    (253, 1, 84305287, N'201203', 5394),
    (253, 1, 40310447, N'201204', 7832),
    (262, 2, 156075, N'201204', 0),
    (262, 2, 156075, N'201204', 0),
    (296, 2, 115181000, N'201204', 1864),
    (296, 2, 105752000, N'201208', 9434),
    (202, 2, 6093671, N'201208', -10087),
    (202, 2, 2810476, N'201208', 5985);


SELECT CONCAT(JD_WS_CD,'_',JD_WS_SUB_CD,'_',JD_SHP_TO) JD_WS_CD_JD_WS_SUB_CD_JD_SHP_TO,
JD_WS_SUB_CD,JD_SHP_TO,
MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(YM,2) = '03' THEN ANT1 END) JAN,
MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(YM,2) = '04' THEN ANT1 END) FEB,
MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(YM,2) = '08' THEN ANT1 END) MAR
FROM @TEMP
GROUP BY JD_WS_CD,JD_WS_SUB_CD,JD_SHP_TO,YM
ORDER BY JD_WS_SUB_CD,YM
```

Output

```
  JD_WS_CD_JD_WS_SUB_CD_JD_SHP_TO   JD_WS_SUB_CD    JD_SHP_TO   JAN FEB MAR
    253_1_29306412  1   29306412    3634    NULL    NULL
    253_1_34300301  1   34300301    1817    NULL    NULL
    253_1_84305287  1   84305287    5394    NULL    NULL
    253_1_40310447  1   40310447    NULL    7832    NULL
    262_2_156075    2   156075  NULL    0   NULL
    296_2_115181000 2   115181000   NULL    1864    NULL
    202_2_2810476   2   2810476 NULL    NULL    5985
202_2_6093671   2   6093671 NULL    NULL    -10087
296_2_105752000 2   105752000   NULL    NULL    9434
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i changed the requirement, can you please re-check?

Comment: The original table is so large that creating a temp table from it would be out of the question

Comment: You can replace @TEMP with your Table.